# Why do I need to specify :location=>some_url(@object) in respond_with in the case of POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am implementing a RESTful API using RoR. Here my `UsersController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    [...]
end

module Api
  module V1
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

      respond_to :json

      def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        @user.save
        respond_with @user, :location => api_v1_user_url(@user)
      end

      def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        respond_with @user
      end

    end
  end
end
```

If I omit the `@user` param from `:location => api_v1_user_url(@user)` in `UsersController#create` i.e. I have it like so:

```
respond_with @user, :location => api_v1_user_url
```

I get the following error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Api::V1::UsersController#create
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"api/v1/users", :format=>"json"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

I just added the `@user` param to `api_v1_user_url` on a hunch after I saw this error and it works.

My question is what is going on here? I do not understand why I need to pass `@user` when most of the examples I've [seen](http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/8/6/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-cleaner-restful-controllers-w-respond_with) do not involve passing the object `@user` to the `:location` attribute.

The output of `rake routes` is a follows:

```
$ rake routes
Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt-3.1.7
          Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                      Controller#Action
    api_v1_users GET    /api/v1/users(.:format)          api/v1/users#index {:format=>"json"}
                 POST   /api/v1/users(.:format)          api/v1/users#create {:format=>"json"}
 new_api_v1_user GET    /api/v1/users/new(.:format)      api/v1/users#new {:format=>"json"}
edit_api_v1_user GET    /api/v1/users/:id/edit(.:format) api/v1/users#edit {:format=>"json"}
     api_v1_user GET    /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)      api/v1/users#show {:format=>"json"}
                 PATCH  /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)      api/v1/users#update {:format=>"json"}
                 PUT    /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)      api/v1/users#update {:format=>"json"}
                 DELETE /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)      api/v1/users#destroy {:format=>"json"}
    static_index GET    /static/index(.:format)          static#index
            root GET    /                                static#index
```

Another place I've seen this (just to name another one):

- [Embracing REST with mind, body and soul](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2009/08/embracing-rest-with-mind-body-and-soul/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason being is that `api_v1_user_url` or `api_v1_user_path` are for a single instance and you need to pass the `id` of that user it should look for and render. Hence why you got the error you go.

In the examples you probably saw `api_v1_users_url` or `api_v1_users_path` which renders all the users. Notice the users_ vs user_

Comment: This makes sense, but I don't see a mention to passing the `id` even in the api docs here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html

Comment: The id is pulled out when you pass the `@user` object because the show action requires the id to be used (also some of the rails magic here).  Also when you generate a scaffold, in my case for `Post` model, you get this: `<%= link_to 'Show', post %>` and `<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %>` which indicate that by passing the object the ID is derived.